# How to force model.matrix() function to consider NA as a level?

Tags: r

How can I force model.matrix() function to consider NA as a level of a group just like "yellow" for example and don't delete that record?
my code:

```
 a    <- c(4,NA, 8, 7, 12, 6, 9, 10, 14, 7,9) 
 b  <- as.factor(c(1, 0, 1,NA, 1, 1, 0, 1,1, 0, 0))
 c  <- c(0.86, 0.45, 0.99, 0.84, 0.85, 0.67, 0.91, 0.29, 0.88,1,0.5) 
 d   <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, NA,NA,NA))
 e  <- as.factor(c(0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0 , 2,0))
 f <- as.factor(c("blue", "blue", "yellow", "red", "red", "yellow", 
                    "yellow", "red", "yellow" , "blue" , "red"))
 g <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 , 0,0)

 mat <- model.matrix(g ~ b + d + e + f)[, -1]
 mat #reduce the number of rows containing NA
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See `?addNA` - as per `model.matrix(~addNA(d) + 0)` - is that what you want?

Comment: I change the code to : mat <- model.matrix(g ~ AddNA(b + d + e + f))[, -1]
but does not work. Did I understand your mean correctly?

Comment: addNA has to be applied to each variable.

Comment: Many thanks. That 's exactly what I've needed.change the code to:mat <- model.matrix(g ~ addNA(b) +addNA(d) +addNA(e) +addNA(f))[, -1]